# Obfuscate Android Test project as well as project (running test on release and obfuscated version)

Tags: android, testing, proguard

Let's say I got an android app project with tests.

Is there any way we can run our test suite (in a separate test project) against the release version ?

Comment: As long as you sign the test.apk with the same release keystore, the short answer is YES, it does not matter whether or not the app.apk and/or test.apk is obfuscated.

Comment: Are you building with ant? I guess you are asking how to test the project built by `ant release`, am I right?

Comment: not really, I am using maven android plugin now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the bounty's comment, I realised OP actually ask something more than a simple Yes/No reply, so I am going to extend my comment to an answer. Generally speaking, a proper designed proguard.cfg and project structure is sufficient to prevent this dilemma.

A typical proguard configuration (see section 7. A complete Android application section in [this link](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html)) guarantee that all android related stuff like Activity, View and etc. is preserved during obfuscation. It doesn't make any sense to alter the configuration for example, to obfuscate Acticity.onCreate() method as it will obviously ruin the application at runtime. In another word, a well design proguard.cfg will protect all public interface to the underlying runtime framework and keep them remain unchanged.

```
... ...

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

... ...
```

On the other hand, Android test project should focus on testing Android component (Intentionally preserved during obfuscation), i.e. a view is proerly rendered, a button click perform correct task, and should avoid writing tests for POJO class that doesn't rely on any Android API, note that these POJOs are what we obfuscate usually. It is better to write pure junit tests for these POJO in the application or referenced java project so that these junit tests are involved at maven test phase before creating the final release (obfuscated, signed and zipaligned). In addition, a good OO design will shield these intermediate POJO dependencies and make them transparent to the outside, i.e. the runtime framework.

```
app/
  src/main/java/
  src/test/java/  <-- intermediate POJO tests put here.
  AndroidManifest.xml
  ... ...
app-test/
  src/main/java  <-- Android component tests put here.
  AndroidManifest.xml
  ... ...
```

It is absolutely fine to write POJO junit tests inside Android test project, however, if you still want to keep the ability to run the test project against obfuscated apk, you need adjust application project's proguard.cfg properly and preserve the POJO class during obfuscation in order to suit the test code.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This is level of details I was looking for. Actually, I may disagree with your advise of excluding POJO tests from android test project. The AndroidTestCase is meant for that (as opposed to InstrumentedTest that test contexts). More over, eclipse doesn't support junit tests insde a standard application layout. And it's even worth with the android maven plugin as test dependencies are included in the app's apk. Preventing obfuscation seems rather troublesome for me as testing should have no impact on code or configuration, especially in released code and released apk.

Comment: 1. AndroidTestCase is not necessary for writing POJO tests as it extends junit.framework.TestCase, so we can use TestCase directly. 2. `it's even ??worse?? with android maven plugin as test dependencies are included in the app's apk`, Are you sure about that? I doubt it, check out the apk, it should exclude test dependencies.

Comment: IMO the instrumentation test is not quite obey the strategy of classical unit-test. the unit-test is usually performed before packing the final release (unit-test failure/error usually halt build process), whereas the instrumentation test is purely at runtime targeting on fully built apk. However, as I mentioned in the last paragraph, there is no simple right/wrong opinion, the whole point is about reasonability.

Comment: lol for pointing out that a closed question should only be answered by yes/no

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct proguard to write out the mapping it creates into a file using the `-printmapping <filename>` directive. The structure of that file is obvious and can be parsed into a Hashtable. Then I would write a script that does apply those conversions onto your tests (making copies of them). Obfuscation simply means replacing class and method names from something (human-readable and) valid in terms of the Java Bytecode Specification to something other (short and not human-readable but) also valid, so this should work. Compile the adapted tests against the obfuscated project and run them.

Comment: Is there any way to tell proguard to use a given mapping ?

Comment: Yes, you can give proguard a mapping file to use when its running.

Comment: Yes, `-applymapping <file>`. See [Usage section in manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/usage.html) for details.

Comment: I still run into problems even after I use -applymapping in my test project to use the mapping of the target project. The problems come from static methods and fields, and instance fields. When accessing these from my test codes, I get NoSuchMethodError and NoSuchFieldError.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your tests and source in one project? if so I believe android maven will strip out the test code when you perform a release.

To fix this you will need to move the tests to a seperate project that links to your actual application (assuming you rely on code/assets of your actual project) then the seperate project will still be able to instrument against a release build of your app (assuming they are signed by the same key).

Comment: I already got a separate project. I am concerned about calls to obfuscated code from the test code.